# Image cannot upload on server using html5 form

Tags: php, html

I have html form which i used to upload image from mobile camera to server. code like below :

```
<form method="post" action="addpreview.php" name="formregister" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="field half first">
    <label for="name">Make Your Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
</div>
<div class="field half">                                            
    <label for="email">Promoted By Text</label>
    <input type="text" name="promoted" id="promoted" />
</div>

<ul class="actions">
    <li>
        <input type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*" capture="camera" style="" class="special fit" />
    </li>
</ul>


<ul class="actions">
    <center>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Let's Preview" class="special" />
        </li>
    </center>
</ul>
```

Then below is code for upload processing in addpreview.php

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {   
    $title = $viral->escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $promoted = $viral->escape_string($_POST['promoted']);



    // upload image

    if (($_FILES['photo']['name']!="")){
    // Where the file is going to be stored
    $target_dir = "upload/";
    $file = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
    $path = pathinfo($file);
    $filename = $path['filename'];
    $ext = $path['extension'];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
    $path_filename_ext = $target_dir.$filename.".".$ext;

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($path_filename_ext)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        }else{
            move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$path_filename_ext);
            echo "Congratulations! File Uploaded Successfully.";
        }
    }
}
```

It's work when i upload file using image from desktop. but upload failed when i tried upload using mobile camera.

Any missing code on mine ?

Comment: Failed as in? any errors or warnings or page crash?

Comment: i tried to check on apache webserver log, but no error found. actually on my code after i upload image to server, image path will save into database. in this case i have success insert new data in database, but image not found on server